# Django not displaying two DetailView

Tags: python, django

Whenever I click on **job_title** link in **index.html**, django redirects me to **detail** url and from there it redirects to **DetailView** in **views.py** file and finally it opens **detail.html** file.
Same thing I am doing for **category** link. But it gives me an error: **No job found matching the query**. (Page not Found **Raised by:    JobPanel.views.DetailView**). I'm getting right slugs from the database to index.html.

**urls.py**

```
path('<slug:detail_slug>/', DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
path('<slug:cat_slug>/', CategoryView.as_view(), name='category'),
```

**views.py**

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Job
    template_name = 'JobPanel/detail.html'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'detail_slug'
    slug_field = 'slug'

class CategoryView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Job
    template_name = 'JobPanel/category.html'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'cat_slug'
    slug_field = 'slug'
```

**index.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'jobpanel:detail' job.slug %}">{{ job.job_title }}</a>

<br>

{% for cat in job.categories.all %}
    <a href="{% url 'jobpanel:category' cat.slug %}">{{ cat }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):

    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Job(models.Model):

    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    job_description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

Comment: The two patterns completely overlap, and thus the first view will always be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: make *non-overlapping* patterns.

The two patterns you defined completely overlap. Indeed, if you have a url with `/some-category-slug`, then that url will match the `<slug:detail_slug>/` pattern and thus trigger the first view. The fact that another `path` also matches is irrelevant, since Django always will trigger the first view in the list that matches.

The best way to solve this is make *non-overlapping* patterns, like:

```
path('detail/<slug:detail_slug>/', DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
path('category/<slug:cat_slug>/', CategoryView.as_view(), name='category'),
```

If you now generate a url for a category, it will look like `category/my-category-slug`. This can not match with the first `path(..)` since that requires that the path starts with `detail`. The opposite holds as well.

Note that you forgot to set the `model` of your `CategoryView` correctly, it likely should be:

```
class CategoryView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Category  # change to Category
    template_name = 'JobPanel/category.html'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'cat_slug'
    slug_field = 'slug'
```

Comment: I've changed the url pattern.
path('detail/<slug:detail_slug>/', DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
path('category/<slug:cat_slug>/', CategoryView.as_view(), name='category')

But i'm still getting the error on category. but this time the error raised by CategoryView.

Comment: @Hussam_7102: you did not change the model of your `CategoryView`.

Answer (score 1):

You define the `CategoryView` like this:

```
class CategoryView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Job
    template_name = 'JobPanel/category.html'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'cat_slug'
    slug_field = 'slug'
```

which will look up the following:

```
Job.objects.get(slug=cat_slug)
```

Looking at your models this seems wrong if `cat_slug` is supposed to point at `job.categories.slug` rather than `job.slug`.

You have left out the code that creates the relation between `Job` and `Category`. It seems to be a 1-to-many relation because of `job.categories` in your template code.

In this case, your `CategoryView` should either:

- subclass `ListView`, keeping `model = Job` and using `slug_field=category__slug`
- or subclass `DetailView`, using `model=Category`, keeping the rest as is

EDIT:

Willem's point of overlapping URLs is of course the other issue here.

If you need URLs without nested paths (`/:slug/` instead of `/job/:slug/`) - you can also use a pattern like `/job-:slug/`.